# FBX loader in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load my model in web using three.js and model is in fbx file .

I tried with this code and model is successfully loaded but i cant get bump in the image like in clothes .

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
            loader.load( 'models/kitty/HelloKityy_HP.FBX', function ( object ) {


                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = false;
                        child.flatshading = true;
                    }
                } );

                scene.add( object );
            } );
```

**This is the image of cloth with no bump :**

[image]

**This is whole image of model in web :**

[image]

and i dont know if i am doing wrong i added normal texture to the loaded object in js :

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
            loader.load( 'models/kitty/HelloKityy_HP.FBX', function ( object ) {


                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.material.normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/models/kitty/normal.jpg');
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = false;
                        child.flatshading = true;
                    }
                } );

                scene.add( object );
            } );
```

and **i got this bump on clothes :**

[image]

but **real problem appear here is that image got unwanted black and white on it which is not desired**  :

[image]

could you please help me on this .

Thansk in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner,
I assume, You need the dress of kitty to be smooth and when you do it using normalisation, whole fbx 3d object gets effect.
To get effect to Dress alone.

1. You can load body and dress separately (as separate files)and add effect to only one as

`loader.load('kitty.obj',obj=>{scene.add(obj)});`

`loader.load('kittyDress.fbx',obj=>{ //can make normalisation or effect to cloth here. scene.add(obj); });`

2. I think there would method or a way to perform normalisation to a portion based on colour filtering.